# C#: Elegant code for getting a random value from an IEnumerable

Tags: c#

In Python, I can do this:

```
>>> import random
>>> ints = [1,2,3]
>>> random.choice(ints)
3
```

In C# the first thing I did was:

```
var randgen = new Random();
var ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
ints[randgen.Next(ints.Length)];
```

But this requires indexing, also the duplication of `ints` bothers me. So, I came up with this:

```
var randgen = new Random();
var ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
ints.OrderBy(x=> randgen.Next()).First();
```

Still not very nice and efficient. Is there a more elegant way of getting a random value from an IEnumberable?

Comment: Assuming you mean `IEnumerable`, but given the question I got an LOL out of `IEnumberable` :)

Comment: What is the source of your `IEnumerable`?

Comment: The RandomElement function appears to be what you're looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql/648240#648240

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate random enum in C# 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319814/generate-random-enum-in-c-2-0)

Comment: @JonH: No, I don't want to generate a random enum.

Comment: @Raymond. The solution you refer to depends on SQL Server while this is pure CLR execution. This is no dupe.

Comment: @Gabe: The source is unimportant. I want to be able to select a random element from any object that implements IEnumberable.

Comment: @George: Since your Python code specifically uses a list and your C# code uses an array, I wanted to make sure you weren't looking for an array-/list-specific solution.

Comment: @Mikael There is no dependency on SQL in the `RandomElement` function. (Other proposed solutions to the question do use SQL, but `RandomElement` does not.)

Comment: @Raymond Oh, I was referring to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 31):

Here's a couple extension methods for you:

```
public static T RandomElement<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable.RandomElementUsing<T>(new Random());
}

public static T RandomElementUsing<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Random rand)
{
    int index = rand.Next(0, enumerable.Count());
    return enumerable.ElementAt(index);
}

// Usage:
var ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int randomInt = ints.RandomElement();

// If you have a preexisting `Random` instance, rand, use it:
// this is important e.g. if you are in a loop, because otherwise you will create new
// `Random` instances every time around, with nearly the same seed every time.
int anotherRandomInt = ints.RandomElementUsing(rand);
```

For a general `IEnumerable<T>`, this will be O(*n*), since that is the complexity of `.Count()` and a random `.ElementAt()` call; however, both special-case for arrays and lists, so in those cases it will be O(1).

Comment: Note however that it makes two passes over the data, which can cause problems if the dataset changes in between the call to `Count` and the call to `ElementAt`. (Not an issue here, but may be an issue in general.)

Comment: True; Jon Skeet's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648196/random-row-from-linq-to-sql/648240#648240 is probably the best one in that regard.

Comment: won't it be a problem if it looks for an ElementAt(enum.Count())? Let's say an enum has 5 items, and the rand chooses 5. Enum.ElementAt(5) will not find anything, right?

Comment: `rand.Next` never chooses its upper bound.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's basically the easiest way. Of course, that's only semi-random, but I think it fits most needs.

EDIT: **Huge Point Here...**

If you only want ONE value randomly chosen from the list... then just do this:

```
var myRandomValue = ints[(new Random()).Next(0, ints.Length)];
```

That's a O(1) operation.

Comment: What do you mean "semi-random"?

Comment: The random class generates pseudo-random numbers, not cryptographically strong random numbers.

Comment: @Chris I know what pseudo-random is. I don't know what "semi-random" is supposed to mean. And being pseudo-random doesn't preclude it from being cryptographically secure, eg: `cryptographically strong != (!pseudo-random)`

Comment: It may be easy, but it is expensive since it sorts the entire enumeration. There are well-known one-pass algorithms for random selection which operate incrementally on the enumeration. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087/select-a-random-n-elements-from-listt-in-c

Comment: Pseudo-random != cryptographically strong.  If you can guess the value, you can crack cryptography based on it.  From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_cryptography: "This term cryptographically strong is often used to describe an encryption algorithm, and implies, in comparison to some other algorithm (which is thus cryptographically weak), greater resistance to attack.  ....  In this usage, the term means difficult to guess."

Comment: @Chris: Wrong. `pseudo-random = !(true random)`, and you can't get true randomness with deterministic computers unless you have specialized hardware (and even then, the randomness is debatable). Wiki on [CSPRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).

Comment: It is random in the sense of not biased towards any particular value, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Sorting will be far less efficient.  Just use Skip(n) and First():

```
var randgen = new Random();
var ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3};
```

<del>ints.Skip(x=> randgen.Next(0, ints.Count())).First();</del>

```
ints.ElementAt(x=> randgen.Next(0, ints.Count()));
```

Comment: Is the last paren supposed to be before `.First()`?

Comment: Why use `.Skip(N).First()` instead of `.ElementAt(N)`?

Comment: You are absolutely right.  ElementAt(N) will be faster for Lists.  Will edit accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

How about something simple and readable:

```
ints[randgen.Next(ints.Length)];
```

Seriously, why obfuscate your code with lambdas .OrderBy and .First and .Skip and so forth!?

Comment: [] isn't going to work with IEnumerable, which is what the poster asked for. I don't think the poster wanted an array or List based solution, which as you point out, is straightforward.