# How can I get a range of integers but exclude some numbers?

Tags: java, range

I need to create an array of integers who will include all numbers between 0 to 53, but some of this integers I want to exclude from the array. Is there any function to do it in Java?

I have an array with the exclusions. There is no logic behind this (In fact, there is a logic, but I don't know how to express this), thus I created an array to specify:

```
int[] exclusions = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 17, 18, 26, 27, 35, 36, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53};
```

I saw seen [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20402263/9550393) of something similar to what I want to do, but in C# (That question is about a random number, which is not what I want, but similar to).

Comment: I'm sorry for any grammar errors in the text. I'm newbie at English.

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, 53).filter(i -> ...).toArray()`

Comment: Your grammar seems fine. And what dictates what numbers will be removed? And the range is so small you could just create a list of numbers and remove from it as needed. Or maintain a set of excluded numbers and check it when necessary.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks. There is no logic to dictate what numbers will be removed. I have an array with all exclusions I need (Forgot to include this in post, omg). But your ideia looks good, check the set of exclusions when necessary. If no solution is presented, I will use it.

Comment: @Brunno shmosel's solution is fairly idiomatic. The filter function oukd define what's kept. I'd go with it. It would be a go way to learn streams too if you don't use them already.

Comment: you should come up with filtration logic which makes some sense to eliminate @Brunno

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yess, I figured I could use stream, because I already knew the filter function, but the problem in this case was: "How to set the range?". Thanks shmosel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a set of numbers you want to exclude and filter the numbers produced by `IntStream.range`:

```java
Set<Integer> exclusions = new HashSet<>();
// add numbers to set
...
int[] numbers = IntStream.range(0,53)
    .filter(n -> !exclusions.contains(n))
    .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it several ways.  First is using the `concat` feature of IntStream.  The following produces a list of 0-5,10-15,and 20-25.

```java
      int[] vals = IntStream.concat(
            IntStream.concat(IntStream.range(0, 6), IntStream.range(10, 16)),
            IntStream.range(20, 26)).toArray();
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
```

You can also just include a list of those numbers to exclude.  This example excludes those in the filter list.

```java
      int[] vals2 = IntStream.range(0, 54).filter(
            a -> !List.of(10, 20, 30, 40).contains(a)).toArray();
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals2));
```

Comment: Stream.of(Range A, Range B, Range C).flatMapToInt(x -> x) , whenever thinking about multiple streams , i feel  its best to flatten

Comment: @Yugansh  I would definitely go with your approach!