# Multiple randomly selection Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have `Questions` table and List of `CategoryIds`. I have to get one question from each `CategoryId` randomly. Right now I'm doing like this:

```
var randomQuestions = new List<Question>();
foreach(int id in categoryIds){

randomQuestions.add(questions.Where(o => o.CategoryId== id).OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

But is there way to do it only with Linq? Thanks

Comment: I hope questions variable not a DbSet<> (if so it's totally awful).

Try that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258824/c-elegant-code-for-getting-a-random-value-from-an-ienumerable

Comment: It is. It's IQueryable<Question> over there

Comment: Why you say "get one question randomly" where you are using this checking o.Id == id?

Comment: Sorry fixed, it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want in one query

```
var randomQuestions = questions
    .Where(q => categoryIds.Contains(q.CategoryId))
    .GroupBy(q = > q.CategoryId)
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(_ => Guid.NewGuid()).First())
    .ToList();
```

That will first filter only questions in the categories you care about, then it groups on the category id and for each group it randomly picks one.